# How do I use indexOf to find a substring and then if it finds it set a value to another part of the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, foreach

I'm working with date-related data (the code parses the dates after this code snippet), but due to some inconsistencies in the data I want to assign a value to the different dates. So if the date is complete it is assigned '0', and then two other levels '1' and '2'. So first I insert three new columns to the array with a default value, which works. But then I want to use indexOf to search for the dates with '00'. The '=== 5' is because it is searching for a substring of the full date 'YYYY-00-DD' and so on. I want the code to loop through the array and find these instances and when it does to assign the relevant number value to uncertainty (the someData[i]["uncertainty"] = 0;). I've been going round in circles trying to get it right so any help is gratefully received.

```js
d3.csv('minimal.csv', function(error, someData) {
        if (error) throw error;

        console.log(someData);

        // 1. add properties 'vstart' and 'vend' for inferred dates
        //    and uncertainty property
        for (let i = 0; i < someData.length; i++) {
          someData[i]["vstart"] = null;
          someData[i]["vend"] = null;
          someData[i]["uncertainty"] = 0;
        };
        
        /* 2. add 'uncertainty' levels:
          0: no uncertainty, e.g. 1898-01-23
          1: uncertainty in days, e.g. 1914-07-00
          2: uncertainty in months e.g. 1906-00-00
        */

        var uncertainty = someData.uncertainty;
          
          for (let i = 0; i < someData.length; i++) {
          if  (someData.indexOf("00") === 5 ) { someData.uncertainty[i] = someData.uncertainty[i].replace(/0/i, 2); }
            
          else if (someData.indexOf("00") === 8 ) { someData.uncertainty[i] = someData.uncertainty[i].replace(/0/i, 1); }

          else if (someData.indexOf("00") === -1 ) { someData.uncertainty[i] = someData.uncertainty[i].replace(/0/i, 0); }

          };
```

Comment: doy ou have some practical data and result?

Comment: Yes dates are parsed after this and used to generate a timeline with datapoints, which does currently work

Comment: At the moment it plots dates with 00 in them incorrectly so I want to assign them a value so that I can map then to particular visual elements to distinguish them from exact dates.

Answer (score 0):

Created demo for you. Please check it.

You are trying to access array **someData** and apply **indexOf()** method. But this method will work on array element. So, you have to access array element by **someData[i]** and then apply the **indexOf()** method.

```js
        
        /* 2. add 'uncertainty' levels:
          0: no uncertainty, e.g. 1898-01-23
          1: uncertainty in days, e.g. 1914-07-00
          2: uncertainty in months e.g. 1906-00-00
        */
          var someData = [];
          someData[0] = "1898-01-23";
          someData[1] = "1914-07-00";

     
          for (let i = 0; i < someData.length; i++) {
          if  (someData[i].indexOf("00") == 5 ) {
            console.log("called 5");
          }
            
          else if (someData[i].indexOf("00") == 8 ) {                         console.log("called 8"); }

          else if (someData[i].indexOf("00") == -1 ) {                       console.log("called -1"); }

          };
```

Comment: will this creation of a new array named someData cause conflict with the array already generated from the csv? Can I not access the already created array? I tried putting in [i] to the code I already have and it gives me this error message "someData[i].indexOf is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (let i = 0; i < someData.length; i++) {

      const regex = /[0-9]+-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/gm;
      let m;
      
      while ((match = regex.exec(someData[i]["start"])) !== null) {
          // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
          if (match.index === regex.lastIndex) {
              regex.lastIndex++;
          }
          
          // month
          if  (match[1] === "00") {
            someData[i]["uncertainty"] = someData[i]["uncertainty"].replace(/0/i, '1');
            console.log('month', match[0])
          }
        
          else if (match[2] === "00") {
            someData[i]["uncertainty"] = someData[i]["uncertainty"].replace(/0/i, '2');
            console.log('day', match[0])
          }
      }




      

      };
```